# How to get rendition copy of word document from alfresco repository using CMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis, alfresco-webscripts

I created one custom web application. through that i am uploading some document to alfresco repository. i also created one PDF viewer to view document in UI.

Now the problem is, i am only able to view PDF type of document, but i am uploading different type of document in repository.

So i want a rendition copy of all documents which i uploaded in repository.
i already have written CMIS code to fetch document and display in viewer.

now i just want rendition copy of document.

can any one help me with this. if possible, please provide sample source code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have well understood your question :

Lets admit that your alfresco is well configured and that when you go on share, your document (.doc & Cie) is rendered in the viewer.

If your document has this nodeRef :

```
workspace://SpacesStore/289e60a1-8b77-48da-ac53-4c2f3e81aa97
```

Then you can have a pdf rendering with this url :

```
https://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/289e60a1-8b77-48da-ac53-4c2f3e81aa97/content/thumbnails/pdf?c=force
```

This way, you always handle pdf in your application.

Be aware that the rendering can take some time and ressource from the server.

Comment: Yep, this is why I was hesitating : I essentially wanted to show that there was a service providing the pdf rendition of a document, even if I wasn't able to answer the CMIS way.

Answer (score 3):

This [blog post](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/cmis/2010/05/17/alfrescos-interpretation-of-cmis-renditions/) discusses Alfresco's interpretation of CMIS renditions and includes Java code that shows how to retrieve them.

To save you a click, the code from that blog post is:

```
OperationContext context = session.createOperationContext();
context.setRenditionFilterString("cmis:thumbnail");
CmisObject doc = session.getObjectByPath("/Sites/ren/documentLibrary/Spring Surf and OpenCMIS Integration", context);
List<Rendition> renditions = doc.getRenditions();
for (Rendition rendition : renditions)
{
   System.out.println("kind: " + rendition.getKind());
   System.out.println("mimetype: " + rendition.getMimeType());
   System.out.println("width: " + rendition.getWidth());
   System.out.println("height: " + rendition.getHeight());
   System.out.println("stream id: " + rendition.getStreamId());
}
```

Which dumps:

```
kind: cmis:thumbnail
mimetype: image/png
width: 100
height: 100
stream id: workspace://SpacesStore/ef7e9a9b-c847-4023-b527-17243c72ade6
```

You can use that stream ID to fetch the actual rendition object and its content stream.